# generate directive dynamically angular4

Tags: angular, directive

I want to know if is possible to render an angular4 directive by using this example:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of sourceElement">
 <{{value.name}}></{{value.name}}>
</div>
```

Comment: read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e#2b99)

Comment: Depending on what is inside, <ng-content> or DomSanitizer might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a section introducing dynamic forms here:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Instead of render a directive in your way, the guide wraps all possible components you may need in a single component.

Then use model to control displaying different component with ngSwitch.